# Google AdMob Android - GDPR consent management - ugly white flash when calling requestConsentInfoUpdate()

Tags: android, admob, gdprconsentform

Google AdMob forces us to use their GDPR consent management to display ads. I followed their recommendations precisely, however on calling:

consentInformation.requestConsentInfoUpdate()

and before the onConsentInfoUpdateSuccess() is hit, even when it determines that getting consent status is not required, there is an ugly white flash over the top 75% of screen. Our main activity has other, non-white colors, so it looks very ugly, and there is no way to avoid this flash or every activity restart...

Here is the code:

```
    consentInformation = UserMessagingPlatform.getConsentInformation(this);
    consentInformation.requestConsentInfoUpdate( // this must be run to get the consent status, but flashes white screen... Darn!
            this,
            params,
            new ConsentInformation.OnConsentInfoUpdateSuccessListener() {
                @Override
                public void onConsentInfoUpdateSuccess() {
                    // The consent information state was updated.
                    // You are now ready to check if a form is available.
                    if (consentInformation.isConsentFormAvailable() && consentInformation.getConsentStatus() == ConsentInformation.ConsentStatus.REQUIRED) {
                        loadForm(icicle);
                    }
                    else {
                        onCreateContinued2(icicle);
                    }
                }
            },
            new ConsentInformation.OnConsentInfoUpdateFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onConsentInfoUpdateFailure(FormError formError) {
                    onCreateContinued2(icicle);
                }
            });
}
```

Is there any work-around for this ugliness, other than resign completely from the consent management, or maybe from AdMob ads entirely?

Additional info: an Android WebView control is the main component of the main activity of my app, on which the consent screen is shown. Not sure if this is important.

Comment: Would consider raising this directly with AdMob. By the way, you probably mean **GDPR**.

Comment: Sorry, memory overflow error with too many acronyms :) Corrected the text now. Not sure how to submit for support directly to AdMob, thought I saw something about posting to StackOverflow anyway such questions. Will see if I can find any other way to reach them.

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved. The WebView control that is the main component of my app, originally shows as an empty white page. I never saw it without GDPR consent, because it's quickly initialized with HTML content to a different default background and contents. The checking if GDPR consent is necessary just delayed this to make the white flash visible.

I simply made the WebView control invisible, and made it visible only after processing of consent if finished. This seems to solve the issue.